# Javascript validation on key down

Tags: javascript

I have the following:  How can I make it validate on key down rather than having to click outside the field?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#repName, #customerName, #orderNo, #itemCode, #itemQty').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#repName').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#customerName').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#orderNo').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#itemCode').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#itemQty').val().length    >   0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
        $("input[type=submit]").addClass('.btn btn-large btn-success pull-right');
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
        $("input[type=submit]").addClass('btn btn-large btn-danger pull-right');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: replace `change` with `keydown`

Comment: How about `.on("change keydown", validate)` so that it validates either way (and thus handles changes made without using the keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#repName, #customerName, #orderNo, #itemCode, #itemQty').on('keyup', function () {
        validate();
    });
});
```

Comment: `function(){validate();}` is the same as just `validate`